# How to parse a specific link using a Selector CSS Query

Tags: css, jsoup

> Note :  A similar question has been asked at [JSoup:How to Parse a Specific
>   Link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35956439/jsouphow-to-parse-a-specific-link)  However, I have a more specific variation of this question - Please read ahead

**To parse a specific site link,  I need to use the`Document` `select()` method to obtain this data in the most efficient manner.  What Selector CSS Query should I use to achieve this?**

Here is one of my attempts that did not compile :

```
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
import org.jsoup.select.*;
import org.jsoup.Connection.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class WebInteraction {

  public Document accLogin(Account ac, String url) {

    Document doc;
    doc = Jsoup.connect(url).data("name", ac.username, "code", ac.pass).method(Method.POST).execute().parse();

    Elements verify = doc.select(a[href*="/logout"]);

  }
}
```

Error Message :

```
$ javac WebInteraction.java
WebInteraction.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
    Elements verify = doc.select(a[href*="/logout"]);
                                 ^
  symbol:   variable a
  location: class WebInteraction
WebInteraction.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
    Elements verify = doc.select(a[href*="/logout"]);
                                   ^
  symbol:   variable href
  location: class WebInteraction
2 errors
```

Comment: Are you trying to target a link with a specific destination in your CSS/JS? If so, you can use a[href*="google"], for example, to target any link containing the word google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error on the following line:

```
Elements verify = doc.select(a[href*="/logout"]);
```

Correct it like below:

```
Elements verify = doc.select("a[href*=/logout]");
```

No double quotes needed around `/logout`.